# Facebook comments iframe does not load more

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-comments, facebook-iframe

We use the facebook iframe to handle Facebook comments on our clients product pages. 
However someting seems to be wrong with the "view more" comments;
it works fine for the first click, but then it stops working.

This problem only occures when you are signed in on Facebook while viewing comments. You need to be signed in to see relpies to comments.

For example this URL (site is in swedish)

http://www.have2have.se/skor/stovletter-skoletter/have2have-brands/stovletter-carola-svart

It has a total of 7 comments. At first the link says "View 5 more".

If I click the view more button, additional comments will be loaded (not 5 however, but that is another question)
and the button will change to "View 3 more".

If I click the "View more" button again it shows a loading indicatior and then changes to "View 2 more". 
but no new comments are loaded.
If I keep clicking the button nothing changes, it just keeps showing loading indicator and "View 2 more".

Is there something wrong with the iframe implementation that I am not seeing or is this a bug on Facebooks side?

Comment: This seems to have been a facebook bug. It has been resolved without me doing any changes at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that from time to time Facebook refuses to load additional comments, after much fruitless debugging i have had to conclude that this was/is a Facebook issue and out of my control.

I recently migrated to Disqus, which offers Facebook connect which from a users point of view is similar and allows them to comment after logging in via Facebook, Disqus allows allow you to connect through Twitter and a number of other services which is nice.

I understand this is not perhaps the answer you were hoping for however i can say based on my personal experience with Facebook Comments, Disqus ended up being our best solution.